# Why can I not keep instances of Firefox from two different machines separate anymore?

Tags: 11.10, firefox, ssh

*Sorry this is a little long. It's one of those issues that's a little tricky to describe*.

I have two computers connected on a LAN. One is running Mythbuntu 11.10, and one is running Ubuntu 11.10 with (the awesome) Gnome Classic.

Before I upgraded to 11.10, I would often sit at Ubuntu machine and use SSH to access programs, such as Firefox, on the Mythbuntu machine. I could do this even if I already had a local instance of Firefox running.

So, just to be clear, before I upgraded I could run two separate instances of Firefox on one machine, each originating from a different machine. One local, and one over SSH from the other machine. One machine's Firefox has different bookmarks and settings than the other.

Now, after upgrading, if I have the local instance of Firefox running, and I try to run another over SSH, I don't get the instance from the other machine. I get a new window of the already running instance.

If I want to run a program from the second machine, I have to first close any instances from the first machine that might be already running.

This is true regardless of which machine's copy I opened first.

I don't know why this changed, but I suppose it doesn't matter. I'm just interested in results. How can I make it so that I can simultaneously run the two different machines' version of any one application at the same time? For example, two different Firefoxes originating from each machine?

Comment: How exactly do you run it "from another machine"?

Comment: I was thinking about **X forwarding** disabled on the ssh daemon. But then you should get an error and not a *local* copy of the application. It might be worth checking `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for `X11Forwarding yes|no`, though.

Comment: @Sergey: As I said, via SSH. Specifically, this command. `ssh -X mythbuntu@192.168.0.12 firefox` So, if I have Firefox running on computer A, and then try to start Firefox using that command, I don't get Firefox from computer the computer at 192.168.0.12, I get another window of Firefox that is already running.

Comment: @MrShunz: In that file I have X11Forwarding set to "yes". I tried setting it to "no", but that did not change anything.

Comment: @DaveMG seems a firefox specific thing. I posted an answer. And `X11Forwarding` should definitively be set to `yes`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11392585) on ubuntu forums. Seems to be a firefox specific thing... BTW, proposed solution is executing firefox with the `-no-remote` option to force it not looking for an already running instance. Can't test it now but seems reasonable.

Comment: You are right. For some reason I had mistakenly thought it was more widely applicable, but actually it is just a Firefox issue. Adding this parameter has solved the problem. Thanks!